# Looking for the name of an anime with a guy who was so fast, he let the enemy's sword practically touch him before he reacted

Tags: shura-no-toki

**More details:**

- The main character preferred fighting unarmed, or with very short weapons, feeling that any long weapon could be countered by getting in close
- This fighting style is unique to his clan, whose name begins with an M (yes, I'm 100% sure of that)
- The main character's final fight was with another good-guy, whose skill was on par with his own
- This other good-guy carried both a katana and a wakizashi (slightly shorter sword), and in one case used one of them as a throwing weapon
- The "other good guy" wore a blue kimono
- The genre is both historically inspired, but slightly "shonen-ized".

I think these details combined are unique to this particular anime.

Looking for the name, but also an opportunity to re-watch. Any helpful links are also appreciated!

I'll keep adding details as I remember them, until someone correctly names it!

**Update**

As Dario guessed, it was *Shura no Toki*. I highly recommend this one because of its similarity to certain historical characters and events.

Comment: I get the feeling this shouldn't have been closed. Nevertheless, could it be [Samurai Champloo](http://myanimelist.net/anime/205/Samurai_Champloo)?

Comment: any idea on what the characters looked like?

Comment: surely, you could recall a bit more details described in the guidelines

Comment: If you could add more details, like what kind of anime it was (samurai kind of anime? fantasy adventure?) and when you watch it, it would help us identify the series easier.

Comment: Just a wild guess: [Mutsu Enmei Ryuu Gaiden: Shura no Toki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6a1GFyNt9E)

Comment: @Dario - **We have a winner!** Thank you!! I guess make an answer out of it, so I can accept it for future reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it is [**Mutsu Enmei Ryuu Gaiden: Shura no Toki**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/340/Mutsu_Enmei_Ryuu_Gaiden:_Shura_no_Toki)

> Legends tell of an invincible martial art known as Mutsu Enmei-Ryu, an unarmed style that allows the user to defeat any number of armed opponents using incredible speed and strength. This is the story of three generations of those who bear the name Mutsu, and their encounters and battles with the strongest fighters of their era.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it could be [Samurai Champloo](http://myanimelist.net/anime/205/Samurai_Champloo)

[image: Samurai Champloo image]

- One of the main characters is called Mugen, which matches your description, of a name starting with M.
- The other good guy (Jin) wears a blue kimono, and uses a katana and wakizashi.
- They have a duel in the end too.

Comment: No, sadly not. *The main character preferred fighting unarmed* doesn't really match up with Champloo, does it?

Comment: I know, but everything else seems to match so well, I decided to give it a try. It could be that your memory was foggy on some things :P

Comment: True. And that reminds me, I need to re-watch SC as well. I *love* the animation style of it, as well as the choreography it adopts.